# PHPUnit Exits with Code 0 Without Running Tests in Dockerized Laravel Project

Tags: php, docker, phpunit

Stack Overflow community,

I'm facing a peculiar issue with PHPUnit in my Laravel project, which is running in a Docker container based on Ubuntu with PHP 7.3. When I execute my PHPUnit tests using ./vendor/bin/phpunit, the process exits immediately with an exit code of 0, but it provides no output or standard error.

**Environment:**

Laravel version: 5.6

PHPUnit version: ~6.0

PHP version: 7.3

Docker base image: Ubuntu 20.04

Attempted Solutions:

I've checked the phpunit.xml file for proper configuration (included below).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <listeners>
        <listener class="Tests\Listeners\TestRadiusAuthListener" file="tests/Listeners/TestRadiusAuthListener.php" />
    </listeners>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

I Ran PHPUnit with --verbose and --debug flags, but no additional output was given.
Checked that the custom listener class in phpunit.xml is correctly implemented and located.

**Questions:**

What could be causing PHPUnit to exit with code 0 without running any tests or showing any output?

Are there any specific Docker or PHP configurations that might interfere with PHPUnit's execution in this context?

Is there a way to debug this issue further to find out why PHPUnit is not behaving as expected?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might have an `exit` or `die` somewhere. You can run a trace using XDebug to see what PHP code is being executed, which branches it takes, and figure out where it stops.